# $ npm install eslint -g = -bash: $: command not found

Tags: javascript, html, terminal, eslint

I am trying to globally install eslint on my mac to use in vs code and it is returning the command not found. does anybody have any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Type only this in terminal `npm install eslint -g` i.e. drop $ from command.

Answer (score 1):

What specifically is not "found"? Is it NPM? If so, check your `PATH` variable.

Since you are using a Mac, it should be here:

```
/usr/local/bin/npm
```

Also, this is a very generic and common question, please do some more research before posting here.

Edit: As per my comment below.

Are you passing `$:` at the start of that command? In most documentation, this refers to the shell command prompt and should not be included in the command.

Comment: $ npm install eslint -g = -bash: $: command not found

this is the input and output in terminal

Comment: Are you passing `$:` at the start of that command? In most documentation, this refers to the shell command prompt and should not be included in the command.